# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable from call to integrate

Tags: sympy

Submitted issue https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12993

---

Is this a bug? Why is this error generated?

```
>python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> A,B,y=symbols('A B y')
>>> integrate(-(A**2+B**2*(-y**2+1))**(1/2)/(-y**2+1),y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1295, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 486, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 919, in _eval_integral
    result = manualintegrate(g, x)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 1223, in manualintegrate
    return _manualintegrate(integral_steps(f, var))
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 1013, in integral_steps
    fallback_rule)(integral)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 85, in do_one_rl
    result = rl(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 85, in do_one_rl
    result = rl(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 65, in null_safe_rl
    result = rule(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 212, in _alternatives
    result = rule(integral)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 33, in conditioned_rl
    return rule(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 176, in _rewriter
    substep = integral_steps(rewritten, symbol)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 1013, in integral_steps
    fallback_rule)(integral)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 85, in do_one_rl
    result = rl(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 65, in null_safe_rl
    result = rule(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 95, in switch_rl
    return rl(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 85, in do_one_rl
    result = rl(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 65, in null_safe_rl
    result = rule(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 335, in mul_rule
    next_step = integral_steps(f, symbol)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 1013, in integral_steps
    fallback_rule)(integral)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 85, in do_one_rl
    result = rl(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 85, in do_one_rl
    result = rl(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/strategies/core.py", line 65, in null_safe_rl
    result = rule(expr)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py", line 743, in trig_substitution_rule
    a = match[a]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Interesting thing is that, if I issue the same command right again, the error do not show up

```
>>> integrate(-(A**2+B**2*(-y**2+1))**(1/2)/(-y**2+1),y)
Integral((A**2 - B**2*y**2 + B**2)**0.5/((y - 1)*(y + 1)), y)
```

It only shows up first time it is used! It looks like using it first time loads something to memory and hence next time the error do not show up.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Surely this isn't intended behavior; so yes, a bug. Executing `expr.match(a + b*symbol**2)` on [this line](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/integrals/manualintegrate.py#L742) returns None, even though `expr` came from `integrand.find(a + b*symbol**2)` a couple lines above. Maybe there's some difference between `find` and `match` here. It's true the error message only shows up on first try, but if you modify the expression (like replace the last 1 by 2) it occurs again.

Comment: tl;dr I suggest moving this report to https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues